# How to add jwt auth to swagger (node + express)?

Tags: node.js, jwt, swagger

I create project like this:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/speed-up-your-restful-api-development-in-node-js-with-swagger

```
swagger project create mega-project
```

How can I add jwt auth to project?
because I don't have idea, how I can do this to swagger :(

Comment: you need a JWT provider, and your Node API is the consumer part. Also, this has nothing to do with swagger, this is very general flow for all APIs.

Comment: https://github.com/auth0-blog/nodejs-jwt-authentication-sample, this would be some example.